# Craft CMS 3 Content Mover

Tags: craft3, database

My database was corrupted after updating to `3.1.0` and no backup. Is there any script to move `fields`, `sections` and other staff to new fresh database?

**Update**
I found something like [this](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts) scripts, but its not that one I needed

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of "corruption", if the 3.1 Control Panel is still accessible and loading, you can use something like [FeedMe](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/features) to export the content you're looking for into a new Craft 3 install.